# How to pass response body values from one thread to different threads by incrementing the values in the response body in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I just wanted to extract value from the response body of thread1(1st thread am running once by passing number of threads and loop count 1 each) and need to pass same for the 2nd thread(2nd thread am running multiple times by passing number of threads 10).
This is my response body from Thread1. 
{"availablePhoneNumbers":["3052191421","3052192726","3052192566","3052195123","3052194493","3052199654","3052194684","3052199164","3052190020","3052190352"]}

i just wanted to pick the first data 3052191421 and wanted to run in thread2 for all the HTTP requests.
then 2nd data 3052192726
then 3rd data and so on.

Could you please get the solution for this?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract first number from the response. This can be done using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) configured like:

   - Names of created variables: `number`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.availablePhoneNumbers[0]`
2. Later on you will be able to use [__longSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) in order to:

   - add 1 to `${number}` variable
   - return the value
   - save the result back into the `${number}` variable

Demo:

[image: JMeter increment variable and save the result]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sorry to say I am not looking for the way u have mentioned. First request is giving back the response of 10 available numbers this is fine. After this i just wanted to create one more thread group and series of HTTP requests, these requests should fetch the first availablePhoneNumber and it should run for all the API's and then second availablephoneNumber with all the API's and so on till the 10th availablePhoneNumber.